# Monodevelop 2.8.6 on windows

Tags: monodevelop

I hope someone can answer this as its driving me crazy.  I have installed Monodevelop on windows XP.  The version being 2.8.6.5. I set the default/active runtime as Microsoft .Net and set my projects to target .net 4.0 via  project settings BUILD-->General->Target framework.

When I debug it from the application output window it loads XSP 2.0 and tries to the old .Net 2 DLL's ie from the .Net 2 GAC - C:\windows\assembly instead of the .Net 4 GAC.

when I debug setting Mono as the active runtime it works ok.

I get the error, which is understandable given the fact the build is targeting .Net 4 yet its looking at the wrong runtime:

Could not load file or assembly 'TestWeb' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'TestWeb' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Here is the output from the Output window:

```
Loaded Module 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
Started Thread 1872
Loaded Module 'C:\Program Files\MonoDevelop\bin\xsp2.exe'
Loaded Module 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MonoDevelop.Xsp\2.8.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756\MonoDevelop.Xsp.dll'
Loaded Module 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
Loaded Module 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
Loaded Module 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
Loaded Module 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
```

many thanks

Simon.